# Taking the mean of square bins in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I currently have a scatterplot with 3 sets of data, an x coordinate, y coordinate, and a value at each x,y. These sets are 1D numpy arrays.

The `matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin` function in matplotlib accumulates all the assigned values at each x,y within each bin, and then takes the mean of it. This produces a colorplot with hexagonal bins.

Is it possible to do something similar, but with square bins, using matplotlib or numpy?

This is the current hexbin code:

`plt.hexbin(daylim,Llim, C = elim, gridsize = 168,bins = 'log')`

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the values to show in the binned 2D plot prior to plotting and then show as an `imshow` plot.

If you're happy to use pandas, one option would be to group the `z` data accordings to cut (`pandas.cut`) x and y data. Then apply the mean (`.mean()`) and unstack to obtain a pivot table.

```
df.z.groupby([pd.cut(x, bins=xbins), pd.cut(y, bins=ybins)]) \
            .mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  matplotlib.colors

x = np.arange(1,8)
y = np.arange(1,6)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":X.flatten(), "y":Y.flatten(), "z":(X*Y).flatten()})

xbins = [0,4,8]
ybins = [0,3,6]
hist = df.z.groupby([pd.cut(df.x, bins=xbins), pd.cut(df.y, bins=ybins)]) \
            .mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print hist
im = plt.imshow(hist.values, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(1,100))
plt.xticks(range(len(hist.index)), hist.index)
plt.yticks(range(len(hist.columns)), hist.columns)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

The logarithmic norm has to be created manually and the ticks need to be labeled according to the binning.

[image]